# Geoserver XYZ tile service

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, xyz, tile-server, xyz-tiles

I am a software developer, and have installed Geoserver to serve Links (Geojson) data in my application as image tiles to frontend.

1. I have found TMS service of Geoserver which serve image tiles in  {z}{x}{-y} format, as it is TMS it follows bottom left grid style so {-y}
2. Here is my Geoserver TMS URL "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/test:Curb_Segments@EPSG%3A900913@png/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png"

**My Question**:

1. I want XYZ tile service form Geoserver. Does Geoserver support XYZ tile service ?. format   {z}{x}{y} not {z}{x}{-y} which TMS.
2. If yes ?. Please provide a sample URL as above I provided.

**My Research**

1. Found Geoserver blob store which has slippy(XYZ), I have configured it to my layer but did not work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the GeoWebCache documentation https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/services/tms.html the flipY parameter is what need.

> The TMS specification has the TileGrid Map origin located at bottom left so Y coordinates grow up moving towards north. A vendor parameter “flipY=true” can be appended to the path to support Y coordinates numbered in the opposite direction, from north southwards.

I do not know in what GeoWebCache version the parameter was introduced.